# DataTables warning: table id=manageTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

why does it return this DataTables error:

> warning: table id=manageTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For
> more information about this error, please see
> http://datatables.net/tn/3

Why does it return datatable reinitialize? I'm using codeigniter framework and here is my folder structure

- controllers

  - Category.php
- models

  - Model_category.php
- views

  - category

    - index.php

my controller is:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->not_logged_in();
    
    $this->data['page_title'] = 'Category';
    $this->load->model('model_category');
    $this->load->model('model_subcat');

}

public function index()
{
    $this->render_template('subcat/index', $this->data);

    $data['category'] = $this -> model_category->getcat();$this->load->view('subcat/index', $data);


}
```

and my ajax is this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FileMainNav").addClass('active');
  $('#categoryMainNav').addClass('active');
  // initialize the datatable 
  manageTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': base_url + 'subcat/fetchSubCategoryData',
    'order': []
  });

  // submit the create from 
  $("#createForm").unbind('submit').on('submit', function() {
    var form = $(this);

    // remove the text-danger
    $(".text-danger").remove();

    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: form.attr('method'),
      data: form.serialize(), // /converting the form data into array and sending it to server
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(response) {

        manageTable.ajax.reload(null, false); 

        if(response.success === true) {
          $("#messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
            '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
          '</div>');


          // hide the modal
          $("#addModal").modal('hide');

          // reset the form
          $("#createForm")[0].reset();
          $("#createForm .form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

        } else {

          if(response.messages instanceof Object) {
            $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
              var id = $("#"+index);

              id.closest('.form-group')
              .removeClass('has-error')
              .removeClass('has-success')
              .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success');
              
              id.after(value);

            });
          } else {
            $("#messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
              '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
            '</div>');
          }
        }
      }
    }); 

    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: The link in the error explains this error quite well. Are you calling your "ajax", which includes the DataTable initialization, multiple times? I can't tell. The reason I ask this is because of the deprecated `unbind('submit')`. You wouldn't need to use this if the code only runs once.

Comment: Simple ways to check this would be: `console.log("Running the code now");` or: `alert("Running the code now");`, directly before the Datatable initialisation.